# Find an element that occurs at least k times in a sorted array in log(n) time

Tags: algorithm

Given a sorted array of n elements and a number k, is it possible to find an element that occurs more than k times, in log(n) time? If there is more than one number that occurs more than k times, any of them are acceptable.

If yes, how?

Edit:
I'm able to solve the problem in linear time, and I'm happy to post that solution here - but it's fairly straightforward to solve it in n. I'm completely stumped when it comes to making it work in log(n), though, and that's what my question is about.

Comment: Good question. What have you got so far?

Comment: This isn't how SO works. You need at the very least provide what you tried.

Comment: By the way, the linear solution can be pretty fast too if `k` is big, as it requires only `n/k` element checks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is `O(n/k log(k))` solution:

```
i = 0
while i+k-1 < n: //don't get out of bounds
   if arr[i] == arr[i+k-1]:
       produce arr[i] as dupe
       i = min { j | arr[j] > arr[i] } //binary search
   else:
       c = min { j | arr[j] == arr[i+k-1] } //binary search
       i = c
```

The idea is, you check the element at index `i+k-1`, if it matches the element at index `i` - good, it's a dupe. Otherwise, you don't need to check all the element between `i` to `i+k-1`, only the one with the same value as `arr[i+k-1]`.

You do need to look back for for the earliest index of this element, but you are guaranteed to exceed the index `i+k` by next iteration, making the total number of iteration of this algorithm `O(n/k)`, each takes `O(logk)` time.

This is asymptotically better than linear time algorithm, especially for large values of `k` (where the algorithm decays to `O(logn)` for cases where `k` is in `O(n)`, like for example - find element that repeats at least with frequency 0.1)

Comment: Good answer @amit!

Answer (score 2):

Not in general. For example, if k=2, no algorithm that doesn't in the worst case inspect every element of the array can guarantee to find a duplicate.

Comment: However given an element `x` you can find out whether it has at least `k` copies in your list in `log(n)` time. But that's a different question.

Comment: There is a a flaw in giving "worst case" performance on a specific argument (that the complexity can depend on it). It's like saying BFS is O(V^2), because E is in O(V^2). This is technically true, but a more common notation for its complexity is O(V+E). Same here, giving a lower bound for the worst possible `k` is silly, since you can offer a better solution that depends on the value of `k`.