# How to find an element in a sorted array that occurs at least k times in less than O(n) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose the array is very large. How to find a element that occurs at least k times in less than O(n) time? Anyone that occurs k times or more is OK.

Comment: A quick search reveals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000231/find-an-element-that-occurs-at-least-k-times-in-a-sorted-array-in-logn-time